# PhpStorm can not auto-completion Symfony Doctrine field name on repository file?

Tags: symfony, orm, autocomplete, phpstorm

PhpStorm version is 2020.1

1. I use `composer create-project symfony/website-skeleton .` to create new app
2. Use `php bin/console make:entity` make new entity
3. `make:migration` and `doctrine:migrations:migrate` to make database table
4. In `Repository.php` file, the `createQueryBuilder('a')->andWhere('a.can not auto-completion')`

I have installed Symfony plugin for PhpStorm.

Why and how to fix it?

Comment: Have you use `repositoryClass` in `@ORM\Entity` annotation onto your entity?

Comment: Check all pages in here: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/symfony-support.html. Could be the missing `@ORM` annotations, may also need to use Php Annotations plugin to support them. Sorry, not a Symfony user here so cannot tell the exact requirements.

Comment: yes,i use make:controller make file